# How to interpret complete genome sequence in NCBI

Tags: database, phylogenetics, sequence

I have a very basic and quick question: does the complete sequence of nucleotides of an organism (for example [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_003413.1?report=fasta) one that I am considering in my homework of Pyrococcus Fuoriosus) reported in NCBI represent the sequence of nucleotides of the forward strand (5' to 3') of DNA?